# PieChart using Prime faces 3.5 and jsf 2.0 coming empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently working on JSF 2.0 application which works as follows:

- 1) upload excel file using Prime faces(woerking fine)\ 2) access data
     and update the third column of excel based on ping testing,set the
     failed and passed count values in MultiplePingtesting bean(works
     fine) 3) ChartBean4 should access the passed and failed count and
     generate graph(Not working) 4) Testing with different files should
     produce proper graph (Not working)

Working enviroment: JSF2.0 with prime faces 3.5, netbeans 7.1 using Glassfish server

***Issue: If  i try to access the failed and passed count in Chartbean4.java it is coming as zero and the piechart comes wrong!!! Please let me know if am wrong any where***

faces-config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>multiplepingtesting</managed-bean-name> 
      <managed-bean-class>control.MultiplePingTesting</managed-bean-class> 
      <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 
    </managed-bean> 
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>chartbean4</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>control.ChartBean4</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>multiplepingtesting</property-name>
            <value>#{multiplepingtesting}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>

    </faces-config>
```

From.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"> 
<h:head>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>:: From ::</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>   
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{multiplepingtesting.handleFileUpload}"
mode="advanced" auto="true"
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/" />    
<p:growl id="display" showDetail="true" />    
<p:commandButton value="suraj" action="PieChart" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

//*******MultiplePingTesting.java***//

```
 public class MultiplePingTesting implements Serializable 
 {
 public int passed, failed; //added getters and setters

 private int i=0,j=0;
 private UploadedFile fileName;//added getters and setters


  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)
    {

        try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        File fName=new File(event.getFile().getFileName());
       fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fName);
       System.out.println("insdie try block ");
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

       POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);
             HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
             String ip,message;
             double port;

             message="";
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("IP");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fName);
                short col=2;
                int lastrow=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;

                for(int rownum=1;rownum<lastrow;rownum++)
                {
                                System.out.println("********" + rownum);
                                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rownum);
                                ip=row.getCell((short)0).getStringCellValue();
                                port=row.getCell((short)1).getNumericCellValue();

                                        try{
                                                    Socket s1 = new Socket(ip, (int) port);
                                                    InputStream is = s1.getInputStream();
                                                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
                                                                if (dis != null)
                                                                {   
                                                                                    System.out.println("Connected with ip "+ip+" and port 21");
                                                                                    message="Connected";
                                                                                    i++;
                                                                }   
                                                                else  
                                                                {   
                                                                    System.out.println("Connection invalid");  
                                                                    message="Connection Timed Out";

                                                                }   

                                                dis.close();   
                                                s1.close(); 
                                          }
                                        catch(Exception e)   
                                        {   
                                            System.out.println("Server not Connected,Connection timed out");
                                            message="Server not Connected,Connection timed out";
                                            j++;
                                        }
                row.createCell(col).setCellValue(message);
                }
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                            setFailed(i);
                            setPassed(j);
                System.out.println("value of failed" + i + "*******"+getFailed());
                System.out.println("value of succes" + getPassed());

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println("exception\n"+ e.getStackTrace());
        }
}
```

//****PieChart.xhtml***//

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"> 
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>:: Piechart::</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body >
    <h:form>   
    <td align="right">      
        <h:outputText value="#{chartbean4.sj}"/>  

        <p:pieChart id="sample" value="#{chartbean4.pieModel}" legendPosition="w"
                    title="Sample Pie Chart" style="width:400px;height:300px"   />
            <h:commandButton name ="multiple_testing" action="From"/>

    </td>

    </h:form>            
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

//****ChartBean4.java****/

```
public class ChartBean4 implements Serializable {

     private MultiplePingTesting multiplepingtesting;
    public MultiplePingTesting getMultiplepingtesting() {
        return multiplepingtesting;
    }

    public void setMultiplepingtesting(MultiplePingTesting multiplepingtesting) {
        this.multiplepingtesting = multiplepingtesting;
    }

    private PieChartModel pieModel;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
   {

         System.out.print("***********multiple_test.failed" + multiplepingtesting.getFailed());
              createPieModel();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel; 
    }

    private void createPieModel() {


     System.out.print("*****Inside Create Pie model******multiple_test.failed" + multiplepingtesting.getFailed());
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel.set("failed", multiplepingtesting.getFailed());
        pieModel.set("success", multiplepingtesting.getPassed());
        System.out.print("***********'");

    }

}
```

Comment: On further check ups, i found 2 more things: 1)If i keep both beans in request scope and use input box for setting passed and failed properties via From.xhtml everythings works perfectly 2) IF i use Upload file event (i.e using handleFileUpload function) and try to set passed and failed properties , the ChartBean4 bean ia not able to access it values --> Please can someone check whether i am setting the values in properties correctly(in MultiplePingTesting.java) and what possible other issues could be in my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Finally i got my answer with some workaround , here are the changes done***

1. Changed both the scope in faces-config,xml to "request"
2. Introduced i and j variables as static in MultiplePingTesting.java.
3. In forward method of MultiplePingTesting failed and passed properties are set using i and j variables

******* *Below are the updated files****************

From.xhtml

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">      
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{multiplepingtesting.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" auto="true" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/" />
    <p:commandButton value="PieChart" action="#{multiplepingtesting.forward}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
    <p:growl id="display" showDetail="true" />

    </h:form>
```

**MultiplePingTesting.java**
(Commented setFailed() and setPassed() code & appended forward() method in file

```
public String forward()
    {
            setFailed(j);
           setPassed(i);

  return "PieChart" ;
    }
```